# How to save empty string in database using Laravel

Tags: php, json, string, laravel, null

This is my controller code:

```
public function addEmployer(Request $request)
{
    $validator = UserValidations::validateEmployer($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation Errors', 'errors' => $validator->errors()->all()], 500);
    }

    try {

        $request->request->add(['created_by' => Auth::user()->id]);
        $employer = $this->employer->create($request->only($this->employer->getModel()->fillable));

        return response(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Employer added', 'data' => $employer], 200);

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation Errors', 'errors' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
    }
}
```

When I save I get `null` values and there is `NULL` in database because field type is `nullable()`,
My `Json` response when I sent empty value

```
"first_name": "Adnan12",
"middle_name": null,
"last_name": null,
"street_address": null,
"suit_floor": null,
"city": null,
"state": null,
"zip": null,
"contact_person_first_name": null,
"contact_person_middle_name": null,
"phone_no": null,
"ext": null,
"cell_no": null,
"fax": null,
"email": null,
"comments": null,
"created_by": 9,
"updated_at": "2019-08-30 13:51:17",
"created_at": "2019-08-30 13:51:17",
```

I want empty string instead of `NULL` in `json` response. How I can achieve this functionality?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to save empty string rather than null? You could setup accessors to return empty strings if the value is null in the database. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators I only say this because from a data perspective storing empty strings instead of nulll values leads to data discrepancies. As in, was the data stored intended to be an empty string or because the value was an empty string.

Comment: agreed but how i can use accessors to implement this functionality?

Comment: @syed1234 you can't do it with accessors since `create()` like `insert()` ignores them.

Comment: How about setting the default of the columns in the database to an empty string?

Comment: Isn&#39;t that why it&#39;s an accessor and not a mutator? If he stores them null like he already is when he accesses the value he converts null into the empty string assuming for his frontend. However, I do see what you mean by passing what is returned from the create method. This is where you would want to use a transformer. Spatie and Freek have a great package for this https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal

Answer (score 2):

In `App/Http/Kernel` class you can find the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` class that is assigned to the property `$middleware`.

This property is an `array` of all the **global middlewares** that run on every request.

You can:

1. Remove or comment out that line so every string input is not converted to null if empty.
2. Write your own middleware if you want to select the fields that could be empty string, something like that:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest as Middleware;

class ConvertEmptyStringsToNull extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the attributes that should not be converted to null if empty.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'middle_name',
        'last_name',
    ];

    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->except, true)) {
            return $value;
        }
        return is_string($value) && $value === '' ? null : $value;
    }
}
```

Now you can replace `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class` with your own `App\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class` in the `$middleware` property of the `App\Http\Kernel class`.